# How to access to user's calendar device using flutter

Tags: flutter

I am writting a simple app to test the functionality of a package that can access to the user's device calendar.
What I did so far:

```
class CalendarEvents extends StatelessWidget {
  final CalendarPlugin _myPlugin = CalendarPlugin();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Calendar Testing',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        backgroundColor: TheBaseColors.lightGreen,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _myPlugin.hasPermissions().then((value) {
              if (!value) {
                _myPlugin.requestPermissions();
              } else {

                Text('We dont have permissions');

              }
            });
          },
          child: Text('Calendar'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also added the permissions for android.
What I need to do is to access to the calendar device. Any idea how?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar

Comment: Yes I tried this package already, but it does not open the calendar from the device but creates a new one